# HTML2Canvas in mobile view takes wrong screenshot in php

Tags: javascript, php, html2canvas

I am taking a screenshot of a div in php using html2canvas. Script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function genScreenshot() {

    html2canvas(document.getElementById('screen1'), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
      
      if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || 
          navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) 
      {
        var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob,'Test file.png');
      }
      else {
        $('#test').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
            $('#test').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
      document.getElementById("screenshot").submit();
      }
      
      
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

it is working fine with desktop[image: Correct screenshot]

With mobile it takes screenshot worngly [image: Wrong Screenshot]

Help me to sort out the issue